# Eclipse Line Endings WikiText Editor

Tags: eclipse, text-editor, eclipse-juno, line-endings, wikitext

I am having a problem with line endings and the WikiText Editor in Eclipse.

If I open a *.textile document outside of a project, line endings are preserved (no CR added).  I can get the two tabs; one for source and another for Preview.

However, if I add the *.textile document to a project, CR's get added to every line.

Since *.textile has a locked encoding, I can't change it.  So, I created my own Content Type (*.textl) and associated it with the WikiText Editor and set the default encoding type to UTF-8.  Same problem occurs.

If I open a WikiText Editor associated file outside of a project, no CR's are added and line-endings are preserved.  If I open a a WikiText Editor associated file that's part of a project, CR's are added.  Note: Line endings in *.c files in the same project  are preserved to Unix style with no CR added.

Any ideas?

Comment: *.textile? Are you sure this is about MediaWiki markup (wikitext)?

Comment: When i generate html from wikitext i always get LF (unix style) which is quite annoying since i am working on Windows and the source files are CRLF